# Include a js and css file only in a specific view

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, php-include

In my CodeIgniter application have a common header and footer view, which I include in different views. My `header_view` is as simple as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <title><?php echo $page_title;?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<!-- end of header -->
```

Now Lets suppose I have another view called `form_view`, where I would like to include a CSS file `form.css` and a javascript file `form.js`. Since these files are only used in form_view, I don't want to add them in the header_view, because then they will be included in all of the views in my application.

So my question remains, how can I include a specific css or a specific javascript file on a specific view, when using a common header like above.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if using a single view for the whole page is a good idea. I'd split the view in header, body, footer... So in your form controller you could load a different header.

Comment: I mentioned above that I have a common header_view and footer_view which I include in all of the views. For example I will include same header_view and footer_view in form_view and other views.

Comment: Are you using a template library or the CI default one: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html ? I'd like to understand how you have included the header in all of the views...

Comment: @Fabrizio D. I am not using any template library, just default CI framework. For example the above code is saved in a view called header_view.php and it is placed in the views folder. Now I have another view called, form_view in the same folder, in that i'd call the header_view by: `<?php $this->load->view('header_view'); ?>`and then rest of the content of the form_view. Similarly i will load the same header_view in another view, login_view. Do you get the idea?

Comment: Ok, got it. You could load a different header_view just in your form_view or split the header_view in a static part and in dynamic (page based) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write something like Zend_Bootstrap and run it before views. The bootstrap file will be responsible for setting css and js files so your header will just grab them from an array.

Bootstrap:

```
$head_array = array(
   'css' => array(
         '/static/css/style.css', 
         '/static/css/style1.css' 
      ),
   'js' => array(
         '/static/js/script.js'
      )
)

if($view == 'view_form') {
    $head_array['css'][] = '/static/css/form.css';
}
```

Of course this example is very primitive but it shows the idea.